# how to get message using post method in HTTP

Tags: html, forms, post, xampp, web-development-server

In my web application there is a contact form where users can contact me, and send me messages but I don't know how to handle this and receive those messages.
I am attaching the screenshot of the particular "contact-me" section as well as code below.
Thanks in advance for helping me out !

```
                        <div class="text">Message me</div>

                        <form class="contact-form" action="#" method="POST">
                            <div class="fields">
                                <div class="field name">
                                    <input type="text" class="fullname" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="field email">
                                    <input type="text" class="email-input" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" class="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field textarea">
                                <textarea class="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button-area">
                                <button class="send-msg" type="submit" name="send">Send message</button>
                                <div class="error-box"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

[contact me screenshot]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64qQH.png

Comment: When you only have a HTTP formular, this won't give you any function like sending a mail. Have you programmed anything yet? You will e. g. need a PHP script which reads out the parameter and then send them via `mail()`. But you will have to code this.

Comment: `<?php
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message)){
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $sender = "From: ab@xyz.com";
            if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $sender)){
                echo "done";
            }else{
                echo "Msg. failed";
            }
        }else{
            echo "enter valid mail";
        } 
    }else{
        echo "req. fields !";
    }
?>
`

Comment: I have this code, but I don't know how to implement this

Comment: You will have to add this code to your page. Which extension does you file has? In most cases the file will need `.php` as extension. Then your code may work (I haven't seen any error yet). But seriously it would be better if you are understanding what you're coding instead of just coping some snippet.